# Store output of every command with timestamp in a file in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

Is there any way to store the output of every command in a log file with a timestamp?
I have tried this script but it did nothing.

```
mkdir /home/my_name/demo |&  tee /home/my_name/My_log.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use >> operator to write your output to file.You can use tee command as well. the only difference is >> doesnt write the output to STDOUT.

have your script or command executed something like below:

```
customScript | ts -r '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]' | tee -a /home/my_name/My_log.log
```

or

```
customScript | ts -r '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]' >> /home/my_name/My_log.log
```

Comment: I have tried your answer it actually it did exactly what i want. Thank you

Comment: @Pasha Happy to hear that it helped. Plz accept the answer if you think your problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

`mkdir` has no output so you won't see any output. Also, you need to use `ts` to get the timestamp.

```
echo hello | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]' | tee ~/my_name/My_log.log
```

`ts` might not be installed on your system, but it can be found in the package `moreutils`.

If you have multiple commands you want to log, you can put them in a script and then pipe the output of the script through the pipeline above:

```
myscript | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]' | tee ~/my_name/My_log.log
```

Comment: thank you  for your answer let me try this...i will update you soon

Comment: it works great with echo command but it also shows the output on terminal which i don't want to                                                 [root@TAG user]# ./test_output_to_log
executing touch command
[2018-04-26 03:42:27] hello
completed

Comment: `ts '[%F %T]'` may be a bit easier...  (and why are you trying to execute a log file?? `# ./test_output_to_log`??)

Comment: @RobinGreen - you may want to mention the `ts` command is provide by the `moreutils` package on Linux -- it's not the same as the `openssl ts` command.